# Datastax Enterprise 5.0.0 on red hat 6.4

Tags: linux, cassandra, redhat, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm using red hat Enterprise Linux 6.4 (can't upgrade for now).

I want to use dse 5 with opscenter 6 in a new product I'm building. The environment is offline and is not connected to the Internet.

1. Will dse 5 work on rhel 6.4?
2. What is the best way to install dse and the opscenter, is it from an rpm or a tarball installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding OS releases and DSE, RHEL 6.4 is not supported / tested with DSE 5.0 and OpsCenter 6, see these links for more info:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/supportedPlatforms.html

Also product compatibility with DSE releases:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html#compatibilityDocument__opsc-compatibility

I personally prefer package installs but as you're using a configuration that might present some issues then you're probably better off with a tarball install. Tarball installs are also useful if you want to have a test platform with multiple releases.